# How to add a header in frame-content container bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My goal is add a logo to header in the `frame-content class`. This is my code:

```
<div id="future" class="frame-content">
        <div class="frame-container">

            <div class="frame-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="appointment_history" class="control-label">
                            <h4>
                            Future appointment
                            </h4>
                        </label>
                        <div id="appointment_future" class="col-md-4 form-control"><div class="appointment_history-row" data-id="69ae226c01cbd83b0ac03b484eb82d95"><strong>gen Venerdì 22/01/2016 15:58:00</strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="command-buttons command-buttons-left">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning home">
                <i class="icon-home"></i>
               Panel   </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16203/)

Essentially, how you can see the label `Future appointment` not have the necessary space to add the logo in the header, so what I want to achieve is insert a logo at the top of `Future appointment` label. But maybe I wrong to chose the `Bootstrap` class 'cause I doesn't have the necessary space for insert a sample logo or any other content. Someone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to do. In case you **just** want to add a logo above the Future appointment label, just add an extra row before this label.

```
<div class="row">
  Logo here
</div>
```

See here https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16207/ again. I updated the jsfiddle.

Comment: Good, seems working fine, and if I want add a footer sticky to the bottom of the main container? Is the same?

Comment: Check the updated jsfiddle for a sticky footer here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16213)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the results will be like this updated fiddle or like below. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16206/)

```html
<div id="future" class="frame-content">
            <div class="frame-container">
<div style="background-size:272px 92px;height:92px;width:272px;background: url(https://www.google.co.za/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png) no-repeat;" title="Google" align="left"><div class="logo-subtext"></div></div>
                <div class="frame-content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="appointment_history" class="control-label">
                                <h4>
                                Future appointment
                                </h4>
                            </label>
                            <div id="appointment_future" class="col-md-4 form-control"><div class="appointment_history-row" data-id="69ae226c01cbd83b0ac03b484eb82d95"><strong>gen Venerdì 22/01/2016 15:58:00</strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="command-buttons command-buttons-left">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning home">
                    <i class="icon-home"></i>
                   Panel   </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```